# Debugging DLL used by web page

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm very new to VS and have a vendor provided web application that we maintain a single DLL for.  In other languages I might have simply done a <%="You are here" + strVar %> type of statement to have debbugging information appear on a web page.  However, I don't know how to approach this now.

I've added the following lines to the method that is called by my web app:

```
    TextWriterTraceListener tr2 = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.IO.File.CreateText("Output.txt"));
    Debug.Listeners.Add(tr2);
    Debug.WriteLine(sqlStr);
    Trace.WriteLine(sqlStr);
    IDataHelper dh = Retrieve.Implementation.GetHelper(this.GetConnectionString(externalConfig));
```

and compiled the DLL with it configured for Debug.  I've then copied the new DLL and PDB file to my web application an ran my web application.  However, I'm not getting any kind of text file in my web app folder nor am I seeing any kind of debugging information outputted to screen.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing or point me to some addtional documentation?

Thank you in advance.

rt

Comment: As you probably know the web application runs on the system as a special user (some kind of IUSR_xxxxx). This user by design has limited rights in the system. Therefore, the file will not be created in the current folder. Try setting the path to a folder with full access for "everyone". On the side note, please read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2faa92k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx about debugging Web Applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and thought I post it here for others.  I needed to install the Visual Studio Remote Debugger on my App server and start the Remote Debugger.  Then in VS, I needed to Debug:Attach to Process... There I was able to browse to my remote web app server, and walk through my code.